# Problem: Publishing image column shows URL of image

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, site-column

we have created a site column via powershell:

```
$siteField=$spWeb.Fields["Floor Plan"]

if(! $siteField)
{
Write-Output "Create new site level column Floor Plan  of type -  Image with formatting and constraints for publishing" 
# Create new site level column "Floor Plan"  of type -    "Image with formatting and constraints for publishing" 
$fieldXMLString = '<Field Type="Image"
Name="FloorPlan"
Description=""
DisplayName="Floor Plan"
StaticName="Floor Plan"
Group="Room Booking Site Columns"
Hidden="FALSE"
Required="FALSE"
Sealed="FALSE"
ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"
ShowInEditForm="TRUE"
ShowInListSettings="TRUE"
ShowInNewForm="TRUE"></Field>'

#Create site column from XML string
$spWeb.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($fieldXMLString) 

}
```

Then, we create a list and add existing column --> publishing site column. When we add item to this list we can see the image url in the column and not the image.

What is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Define these two attributes for the field:

`RichText="TRUE" RichTextMode="ThemeHtml"`